# Obtengo "Acceso prohibido" al correr Symfony 1.2

Tags: php, symfony2

he se seguido al pie de la letra el [tutorial oficial](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/jobeet/1_2/en/01?orm=Propel) para crearme una instalación de Symfony 1.2 en mi computadora local (Windows 10 + Xampp). (Por cuestiones de trabajo, necesito una instalación de Symfony 1.x, así que no me sirve de nada una versión más reciente.)

Ya llegué al último paso, donde creo el VirtualHost, pero a la hora de acceder al proyecto mediante el navegador, éste me devuelve un error 403: ¡Acceso prohibido!

Sin éxito ya intenté quitar el read-only de la carpeta *web* del proyecto (no pude quitárselo, ni con la consola ni con el explorer).

Mi virtual host está así:

```
<VirtualHost *:888>
  DocumentRoot "c:/development/sfprojects/jobeet/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web"
  ServerName www.symfonytest.local
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  <Directory "c:/development/sfprojects/jobeet/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>

  Alias /sf c:/development/sfprojects/jobeet/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf
  <Directory "c:/development/sfprojects/jobeet/lib/vendor/symfony/data/web/sf">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Conseguiste acceder? tendrias algún problema con la configuración. Ademas te falta añadir al archivo C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts el ServerName y la ip. Me explico?

Answer (score 0):

si te dice que no tienes permiso es porque la carpeta donde tiene tu proyecto que en apache es www o htdocs no tiene permiso de usuario, debes asignarle los permisos para que puede ser leida y accedida por todos los usuarios de forma recursiva es decir con todos sus archivos incluidos